# Lock json object and its child elements in multithreaded environment - best practice

Tags: c#, .net

So I have JSON object which is shared between more threads, I would like to know best practices how to lock it when reading/writing to it. Should I use the same lock object even when accessing different child elements of this object, or should I create own lock objects for each child element. Or should I lock object onto itself (or onto its elements accordingly)?

Comment: What is a "JSON object"? In C# JSON is stored in strings, and objects are objects, they don't mix. Please show relevant code

Comment: Newtonsoft.JSON object instance, to be specific

Comment: Newtonsoft has a `JObject`, is that what you mean by "Newtonsoft.JSON object instance"? Locking is going to depend on whether your threads are modifying the same object, or only modifying the child objects of the root (meaning not changing the keys or values of the root object). **Please show your code.**

Comment: the code is not relevant, I am asking about best practices for this problem. Lets's say threads are modifying parent object and also child objects - should I lock it with same lock object, or use different for better performance? But since amount of child objects is variable, is it safe to do this: lock(childJsonObject){
//modifying childJsonObject
} ?

Comment: "Is it safe" is very dependent on the code and how it accesses these child objects. If it's actually *replacing* the child objects at the root level then it will not be thread-safe unless you lock against the parent also. There is no "best-practice", it's a case-by-case analysis of what cross-thread operations you are actually doing

Comment: Best practice is simple: don't share data across threads, this always introduces complexity and potential for bugs. Prefer splitting and merging work with immutable data structures, making copies if you have to. Where sharing can't be avoided, don't try to get clever but do the simplest thing that's obviously correct (like locking on a private `object` specifically created for that purpose) unless actual profiling results show a bottleneck that justifies more subtle strategies.

Comment: Whenever you have to ask the question "is this particular locking strategy safe given this and this object type" you should proceed straightforwardly, by assuming the answer is "no", as *generally* types aren't written with any kind of thread safety in mind unless the author has explicitly documented it (and then hopefully what *kind*). For JSON.NET, the *only* documentation is [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonNetVsDotNetSerializers.htm), which merely shows a green checkmark next to the words "thread safe" with no further clarification, which I'd call *worse* than nothing.